# C# TabControl内に張り付けたコントロールが肥大化する

Tags: c#

お世話になります。

C#にて、TabControlをフォームに貼り付け、その中のTabPageに自分の作った
PanelやUserControl(内部にButtonやTextBoxがあるものとする)を
貼り付けます。
その時に、TabControlのFontに大きなフォントサイズを指定すると、
それに合わせて自分の作ったコントロールの中のButtonなどのコントロールが
肥大化し、レイアウトが崩れてしまいます。

これを回避する方法はありますでしょうか。

細かなことですみませんが、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 自動スケーリングの問題だと思われます。
AutoScaleMode に AutoScaleMode.Noneを指定し自動スケーリングを無効にすると解決できる場合があります。

できればWindowsフォームより、WPFを使用することを推奨します。
フォームでは、近年の高解像度環境への対応が困難になる場合があります。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
ご指摘の通り、AutoScaleMode.Noneにしたところ、正しく表示されました。
言い訳になるかもしれませんが、このプロパティは自分で変更した覚えが
ないのですが、いつの間にかFontになっていました。
自然に変わってしまうものなのでしょうか。
何はともあれも無無事に解決できました。
教えていただいたWFPも、少し見てみましたが、面白そうなので
取り組んでみようと思います。
ありがとうございました。

Comment: AutoScaleMode は、デザイナが自動的に設定します。
※ VSのバージョンにもよって初期値が異なる。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己レスです。
AutoScaleModeをAutoScaleMode.Noneにすることで解決できました。